# Table schema column data type equivalents for Netezza 6 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration, datatypes, netezza

I'm trying to find a data type equivalents for data types in Netezza when migrating table schema to SQL Server.  Where can I find a complete list?  When getting down to brass tacks, I am specifically looking for Netezza 6 & SQL Server 2008.

Here is a complete list of the data types we're using in Netezza.  Obviously some of these are dependent on length.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT_TYPE
FROM _v_relation_column


ABSTIME
BIGINT
BOOLEAN
BYTEA
BYTEINT
CHAR
CHARACTER VARYING(1)
CHARACTER VARYING(10)
CHARACTER VARYING(100)
CHARACTER VARYING(1000)
CHARACTER VARYING(10000)
CHARACTER VARYING(1024)
CHARACTER VARYING(108)
CHARACTER VARYING(11)
CHARACTER VARYING(110)
CHARACTER VARYING(1100)
CHARACTER VARYING(117)
CHARACTER VARYING(12)
CHARACTER VARYING(120)
CHARACTER VARYING(1200)
CHARACTER VARYING(128)
CHARACTER VARYING(13)
CHARACTER VARYING(14)
CHARACTER VARYING(140)
CHARACTER VARYING(15)
CHARACTER VARYING(150)
CHARACTER VARYING(1500)
CHARACTER VARYING(157)
CHARACTER VARYING(16)
CHARACTER VARYING(160)
CHARACTER VARYING(17)
CHARACTER VARYING(1700)
CHARACTER VARYING(18)
CHARACTER VARYING(1800)
CHARACTER VARYING(184)
CHARACTER VARYING(188)
CHARACTER VARYING(19)
CHARACTER VARYING(192)
CHARACTER VARYING(2)
CHARACTER VARYING(20)
CHARACTER VARYING(200)
CHARACTER VARYING(2000)
CHARACTER VARYING(201)
CHARACTER VARYING(2048)
CHARACTER VARYING(206)
CHARACTER VARYING(21)
CHARACTER VARYING(22)
CHARACTER VARYING(220)
CHARACTER VARYING(23)
CHARACTER VARYING(24)
CHARACTER VARYING(25)
CHARACTER VARYING(250)
CHARACTER VARYING(2500)
CHARACTER VARYING(254)
CHARACTER VARYING(255)
CHARACTER VARYING(256)
CHARACTER VARYING(26)
CHARACTER VARYING(27)
CHARACTER VARYING(28)
CHARACTER VARYING(3)
CHARACTER VARYING(30)
CHARACTER VARYING(300)
CHARACTER VARYING(31)
CHARACTER VARYING(32)
CHARACTER VARYING(33)
CHARACTER VARYING(35)
CHARACTER VARYING(350)
CHARACTER VARYING(37)
CHARACTER VARYING(38)
CHARACTER VARYING(4)
CHARACTER VARYING(40)
CHARACTER VARYING(400)
CHARACTER VARYING(4000)
CHARACTER VARYING(401)
CHARACTER VARYING(428)
CHARACTER VARYING(4282)
CHARACTER VARYING(450)
CHARACTER VARYING(46)
CHARACTER VARYING(5)
CHARACTER VARYING(50)
CHARACTER VARYING(500)
CHARACTER VARYING(5000)
CHARACTER VARYING(508)
CHARACTER VARYING(51)
CHARACTER VARYING(510)
CHARACTER VARYING(512)
CHARACTER VARYING(55)
CHARACTER VARYING(6)
CHARACTER VARYING(60)
CHARACTER VARYING(600)
CHARACTER VARYING(62)
CHARACTER VARYING(64)
CHARACTER VARYING(66)
CHARACTER VARYING(66046)
CHARACTER VARYING(7)
CHARACTER VARYING(70)
CHARACTER VARYING(700)
CHARACTER VARYING(75)
CHARACTER VARYING(77)
CHARACTER VARYING(79)
CHARACTER VARYING(8)
CHARACTER VARYING(80)
CHARACTER VARYING(800)
CHARACTER VARYING(8190)
CHARACTER VARYING(84)
CHARACTER VARYING(88)
CHARACTER VARYING(9)
CHARACTER VARYING(90)
CHARACTER VARYING(91)
CHARACTER VARYING(999)
CHARACTER(1)
CHARACTER(10)
CHARACTER(15)
CHARACTER(2)
CHARACTER(25)
CHARACTER(3)
CHARACTER(4)
CHARACTER(5)
CHARACTER(6)
CHARACTER(7)
CHARACTER(8)
DATE
DOUBLE PRECISION
INT2VECTOR
INTEGER
INTERVAL
NAME
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(1)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(10)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(1024)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(16)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(16000)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(188)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(195)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(20)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(200)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(255)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(256)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(3)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(31)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(5)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(50)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(600)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(7)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(8)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(8192)
NUMERIC(1,0)
NUMERIC(10,0)
NUMERIC(10,2)
NUMERIC(10,3)
NUMERIC(10,4)
NUMERIC(11,0)
NUMERIC(12,0)
NUMERIC(12,2)
NUMERIC(12,3)
NUMERIC(12,8)
NUMERIC(13,3)
NUMERIC(14,0)
NUMERIC(15,0)
NUMERIC(16,15)
NUMERIC(17,2)
NUMERIC(18,0)
NUMERIC(18,1)
NUMERIC(18,10)
NUMERIC(18,2)
NUMERIC(18,3)
NUMERIC(18,4)
NUMERIC(18,5)
NUMERIC(18,6)
NUMERIC(2,0)
NUMERIC(2,1)
NUMERIC(20,0)
NUMERIC(20,10)
NUMERIC(20,8)
NUMERIC(25,24)
NUMERIC(28,0)
NUMERIC(28,2)
NUMERIC(3,0)
NUMERIC(3,1)
NUMERIC(34,6)
NUMERIC(38,0)
NUMERIC(38,10)
NUMERIC(38,2)
NUMERIC(38,20)
NUMERIC(38,4)
NUMERIC(38,6)
NUMERIC(38,8)
NUMERIC(4,0)
NUMERIC(5,0)
NUMERIC(5,2)
NUMERIC(6,2)
NUMERIC(7,2)
NUMERIC(7,3)
NUMERIC(8,0)
NUMERIC(8,2)
NUMERIC(9,3)
NUMERIC(9,4)
NUMERIC(9,6)
OID
OIDVECTOR
REAL
REGPROC
SMALLINT
TEXT
TIME
TIME WITH TIME ZONE
TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/66009/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0uy5o71b8qeu7n1oi7yz564bokn.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this guide](http://www.enzeecommunity.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/1161-102-1-1107/Netezza_database_users_guide.pdf) which is for Netezza version 5, so that should be close. Documentation for that system is rather difficult to find, or at least it doesn't readily show up on Google. For SQL Server 2008, the MSDN page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
ABSTIME --> ??
BIGINT --> bigint
BOOLEAN --> bit
BYTEA --> ?? tinyint?
BYTEINT --> smallint (tinyint is positive values only)
CHAR --> char(1)
CHARACTER VARYING(1..8000) --> varchar(1..8000)
CHARACTER VARYING(>8000) --> varchar(MAX)
CHARACTER(1..8000) --> char(1..8000)
DATE --> date
DOUBLE PRECISION --> double precision or float(53)
INT2VECTOR --> ??
INTEGER --> int
INTERVAL --> No equivalent
NAME --> ?? sysname?
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(1..4000) --> nvarchar(1..4000)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(>4000) --> nvarchar(MAX)
NUMERIC(p,s) --> numeric(p,s)
OID --> ??
OIDVECTOR --> ??
REAL --> real
REGPROC --> ??
SMALLINT --> smallint
TEXT --> ?? Probably either varchar(MAX) or nvarchar(MAX)
TIME --> time(6)
TIME WITH TIME ZONE --> datetimeoffset(6)
TIMESTAMP --> datetime2(6)
```

Comment: I'll be testing these tomorrow and will let you know how it goes

Comment: this worked perfectly!

Comment: @MacGyver: Great! Glad to hear it.

Comment: `DOUBLE PRECISION` is equivalent to `float(15)` - `REAL` is equivalent to `float(6)`.

Comment: @cairnz: Yes, but that's Netezza's `float` data type, which has a different range of precision argument than SQL Server.